# "Ça m'est égal" avec d'autres noms et pronoms

Tags: expressions, pronoms

L'expression *Ça m'est égal* est très couramment utilisée pour dire que le locuteur est indifférent entre les choix présentés. Peut-on utiliser cette expression également avec d'autres noms ou pronoms ?

> A: Quel cadeau devrions-nous acheter pour Jean ?
>
> B: Je ne sais pas. Je pense que ça lui est égal. / Je pense que c'est égal à Jean.

Comment: "Ça lui est égal" est correct, mais je suis mitigé pour "c'est égal à Jean". D'autre part, le registre de ta phrase est un peu hésitant. Utiliser "nous" indique du langage assez soutenu, on utiliserait plutôt "devrions-nous" que "est-ce que nous devrions".

Comment: Je pense que "c'est égal à Jean" est correct, en tout cas je l'ai déjà vu ou entendu (mais pas forcément avec "Jean" :o) ).

Comment: @SimonDéchamps J'aurais fortement tendance à dire "Jean, ça lui est égal". Je ne doute pas que ça se rencontre sans pronom, mais ça me semble assez rare.

Comment: "ça lui est égal" - yes.  "c'est égal à Jean" - so stilted, so.. 17th century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, on peut utiliser différents pronoms. Par contre, je n'ai vu une utilisation avec un nom.

> Ça m'est égal.
>
> Ça t'est égal.
>
> Ça lui est égal.

Sinon, on peut utiliser *importe peu*, comme dans :

> Cela m'importe peu.
>
> Cela t'importe peu.
>
> Cela l'importe peu.
>
> Cela nous importe peu.
>
> Cela vous importe peu.
>
> Cela les importe peu.
>
> Ces exemples vous importent peu.

Comment: Je pense que c'est plutôt "cela **lui** importe peu" et "cela **leur** importe peu".

Comment: @SimonDéchamps On rencontre "cela l'importe peu" et "cela les importe peu". Différence de niveau de langue ? Régionalisme ?

Comment: @Laure Hmm je ne vois pas trop pourquoi. "Importer à quelqu'un" donc pronom COI me/te/se/lui/nous/vous/leur. Ça ne me paraît pas sujet à débat mais je loupe peut-être un truc.